# IF ELSE Statement under LINQ's WHERE clause

Tags: c#, linq

```
 where task.RevisionDateTime > startDateTime_
                            && task.RevisionDateTime <= endDateTime_
                            && task.AutoAuditNotes.ToLower() != auditString.ToLower()
                            && (if(isStaging_) condition1 else condition2)
                            select task).ToList();
```

Under where clause I have this IF ELSE Statement `&& (if(isStaging_) condition1 else condition2)`. How can I Add condition under WHERE clause defends on the value of `isStaging_` variable?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the question is a little confusing because `_isStaging` *is* the condition.

Comment: @un-lucky NO they are conditions like:  && `(if(isStaging_) task.IsCurrent == true else task.AutoAuditNotes.ToLower() != auditString.ToLower() )`

Comment: I think condition1 is the condition if isStaging_ is true, else it will be condition2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
where task.RevisionDateTime > startDateTime_
                        && task.RevisionDateTime <= endDateTime_
                        && task.AutoAuditNotes.ToLower() != auditString.ToLower()
                        && ((isStaging_ && condition1) || condition2)
                        select task).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks It works but I having hard time understanding the code :) sorry for that, Can you explain it for me? Thank you

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a direct answer - I upvoted KiNeTiC's answer. But this comment requires some code formatting that can't go into a comment.

This will become much more readable if you break conditions into separate functions. For example, whatever this is:

```
&& ((isStaging_ && condition1) || condition2)
```

Put it in its own function with a name describing what it's checking. The branching will make it difficult for someone to read and follow, even the person who wrote it a week later. But if it's a function call then the name of the function serves as a comment.

Long LINQ queries are oddly satisfying to write, but it can be very difficult for someone else to understand what they're doing.

Comment: Oh I totally agree with you on this one.

Answer (score 0):

you try

```
if(isStaging_)
{
    //condition1
    where task.RevisionDateTime > startDateTime_
                        && task.RevisionDateTime <= endDateTime_
                        && task.AutoAuditNotes.ToLower() != auditString.ToLower()
                        select task).ToList();
}
else
{
    //condition2
    where task.RevisionDateTime > startDateTime_
                        && task.RevisionDateTime <= endDateTime_
                        && task.AutoAuditNotes.ToLower() != auditString.ToLower()
                        select task).ToList();
}
```